# PTP Mount iphone on macOS BigSur

Tags: macos, iphone, mount, graphics

On Windows, it is super easy to mount an iPhone via PTP.

```
Picture Transfer Protocol
```

It is recognized as a "Camera".
This shows the iPhone as Drive in Explorer and gives access to all pictures.

Goals:

- No Use of 3rd Party Tools
- No Use of Apps (Photos, ImageCapture...)

How can this PTP mount be done on Mac (BigSur and above)?

Comment: Windows has to mount it as USB Storage & PTP because it can't mount it properly. Mac mounts it properly & never handles it like some kind of external drive/camera combo. The only way I know of to poke around inside is to use iMazing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not working on macOS, as like Tetsujin said, the mounting mechanism is working completely different.